# declaring nodes in a \draw command relative to other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Why doesn't the commented-out line work? I would like to place a node (an anonymous one actually) declared in a \draw command.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\title{arrow test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
  font=\sffamily,
]

\node[draw, thin, black, fill=green, rectangle] (P1) at (0cm,0cm){};
\node[draw, thin, black, fill=red, rectangle, right=1cm of P1] (P2){};
\node[draw, thin, black, fill=green, rectangle] (P3) at (0cm,0.5cm){};
\draw[->] (P1) -- (P2);
%\draw[->] (P3) to node[draw, thin, black, fill=red, rectangle, right=1cm of P3](P4){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\title{arrow test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%>=latex,
    node distance = 10mm,
box/.style = {rectangle, draw, thin, fill=#1, font=\sffamily},
                    ]
\node[box=green]            (P1) at (0cm,0cm)  {};
\node[box=red, right=of P1] (P2)    {};
\node[box=green]            (P3) at (0cm,1cm)   {};

\draw[->] (P1) -- (P2);
\draw[->] (P3) node[box=red, right=of P3] (P4) {} -- (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Coordinates can not be "bootstrapped" ... first you need to define it and after than use it. Compare the last line in your and mine MWE.

Comment: so there's no way to draw an arrow to an anonymous node, then?

Comment: as far as I know TikZ, no. this is similar to post: it is impossible to send a letter to unknown address ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost what you want, the flaw being that the 1cm distance is calculated from the center of the first node (so in the example the two right-hand nodes are not correctly aligned)

```
 \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
 \begin{document}
 \title{arrow test}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
   font=\sffamily,
 ]

 \node[draw, thin, black, fill=green, rectangle] (P1) at (0cm,0cm){};
 \node[draw, thin, black, fill=red, rectangle, right=1cm of P1] (P2){};
 \node[draw, thin, black, fill=green,opacity=0.5, rectangle] (P3) at (0cm,0.5cm){};
 \draw[->] (P1) -- (P2);
 \draw[->] (P3) -- +(1cm,0)  node[draw, thin, black, fill=red, rectangle, right] (P4) {};

 % \draw[->] (0,0.5cm) node[draw, thin, black, fill=green,opacity=0.5,
 % rectangle,left] {} -- +(1cm,0) node[draw, thin, black, fill=red, rectangle,
 % right] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

So in some sense it is possible to draw anonymous nodes, the problem is that it works only for two nodes as you would need to change the starting point of for a successive path, which is not possible if the node is anonymous.

Comment: The two right-hand nodes are not correctly aligned